# static images in php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

i did this snippet :

- File captcha.php

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<script>
setInterval(function(){chrono('t');},1000);
</script>
<?php
include('function.php');
session_start();
global $list;


$list= captcha_list($_SESSION['id']);
if (isset($_POST['know'])){
?>
<script>
inte = 0;
var string ='<?php
$str='';
 $x=sizeof($list);

      for($j=0;$j < $x;$j++)
    { 

     for($i=0;$i < 7;$i++)
    { 

          $str=$str.$list[$j][$i].';'; 
          }
     } 
echo $str.$list[$x-1];
?>';
var count='<?php 
$x1=sizeof($list);
echo $x1;
?>';
var table =string.split(';');
var longuer=table.length-1;
currentElement=15;
document.getElementById("im").src=table[currentElement];
</script>
<?php
}
?>



<script>

function chrono(id){

 inte= parseInt(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML,10);

var string ='<?php
$str='';
 $x=sizeof($list);

      for($j=0;$j < $x;$j++)
    { 

     for($i=0;$i < 7;$i++)
    { 

          $str=$str.$list[$j][$i].';'; 
          }
     } 
echo $str.$list[$x-1];
?>';
var count='<?php 
$x1=sizeof($list);
echo $x1;
?>'
var table =string.split(';');

var longuer=table.length-1;

if ( typeof this.currentElement == 'undefined' ) this.currentElement = 1;

switch(inte)
{
case 0:

document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='7';
if(currentElement==count*7-6){
currentElement=1;

}else{

currentElement+=7;

}

document.getElementById("im").src=table[currentElement];

  break;

case 1:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='0';
break;

 case 2:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='1';
break;

  case 3:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='2';
   break;

  case 4:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='3';
  break;

  case 5:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='4';
   break;

  case 6:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='5';
  break;

  case 7:
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML='6';

break;

default:
    break;
}

};
</script>
</head>







<body style="background-image:url(paper_03.png)" >

 <form name="form_2"  style="background-image:url(paper_02.png);position: absolute; top:30px; left: 200px; width: 500px; height: 500px;"  method="post" >
                    <CENTER>
                        <table style="position: relative; top:30px;" >
                    <tr><td colspan=4><label>Image will be refresh in <label id="t" name="t"> 7 </label>  seconds
                     </label></td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td height=200px ><label>Image </label></td><td></td><td height=200px colspan=2><input type="image" id="im" src=<?php  echo $list[0]['captcha'];?> style=" height=150px" /> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td height=200px><label>Text </label></td><td colspan=3 height=200px><input type="text" name="cap" style="width: 400px" /> </td></tr>
                    <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="answer" value="SUBMIT ANSWER" style="height:200%;background-image:url(paper_03.png)"/> </td><td><input type="submit" name="know" value="DON'T KNOW" style="height:200%; background-image:url(paper_03.png)"/> </td><td><input type="submit" name="pause" value="SUBMIT AND PAUSE" style="height:200%;background-image:url(paper_03.png)"/> </td>
                    </tr>


                </table>

    </CENTER>
</form>     
</body>
<footer>
<?php 
include('header_footer/footer.php');
?>
</footer>


</html>
```

the images passed one by one without problem but if i click in button "know" the page refresh and the first image is displayed. i want if i click in "know" the next image will display.

1. what is the error?
2. how can i fix it?

Comment: parts of switch statements can be replaced with `if(parseInt(inte, 10)>0&&parseInt(inte, 10)<8) document.getElementById(id).innerHTML=parseInt(inte, 10)-1`

Comment: no my problem is how to get the index of the next image in table when i refresh the page by clicking in button?